# Only the last added items will delete in Firebase Realtime Database in Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Please bear with me as am I new in Firebase. I have created an app to let the user add items and category. What I did is that when I add a category, I save the `CategoryId` or key in a Shared Preference and when I want to retrieve it, I compare it with the keys inside the Category.

What happened here is that only the last item that I added will be deleted, it won't delete other items after that.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code below? Thanks for any help.

Here is my structure

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public void deleteCategory(){
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("OwnerPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String username = (shared.getString("owner_username", ""));

        SharedPreferences categoryshared = getSharedPreferences("CategoryPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String catId = (categoryshared.getString("category_id",""));


        ownerdbreference.orderByChild("business/owner_username").equalTo(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        final String ownerkey = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                        ownerdbreference.child(ownerkey+"/business/category").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                        String categorykey = dataSnapshot2.getKey();
                                        if (categorykey.equals(catId)){
                                            dbreference.child("owner/"+ownerkey+"/business/category").child(catId+"/category_name").setValue(null);
                                            Toast.makeText(EditCategory.this, "Item deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            finish();
                                        }else{
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(EditCategory.this, "Does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Did you try `removeValue()` instead of  `setValue(null)`?

Comment: Yes I've tried it first. I think there's a problem with how I store the key in my shared preference

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your code u only delete item which has key equal to last saved key in shared pref.

Retrieving value from shared pref

```
final String catId = (categoryshared.getString("category_id",""));
```

Deleting item depend on this key

```
if (categorykey.equals(catId))
```

So if you need to delete all items without condition you can simply remove above condition.

Or if you need to delete with the condition you must store all keys you can use SQLITE (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) -the best way-

Or you can store keys as Json in shared pref.

Then you can delete all depend on keys list.

Comment: Is there a way to check they key of an item that I want to visit without saving the ID in shared preference?

Comment: you can read key you want first then you can use them in your condition